# #pragma scalar_storage_order directive in c++ ignored

Tags: c++, c, boost, endianness

im trying to find out how to declare a structure with endianess big-endian.
The reason is because i have a uint8_t* payload which i want to "reinterpret_cast" to a structure which is big-endian without the needs to do in-place swap or whatever.
With gcc i can do

```
#pragma scalar_storage_order big-endian
typedef struct {
    uint16_t srv_id;
} __attribute__((packed)) server;
```

and by invoking gcc -Wall i can compile and debug it showing it works.

Currently i am in need to have the same with g++ but when i use the same code i receive a Warning that the compiler is ignoring the pragma.

I would like to understand the following?

1. Is there an alternative way to declare it as such?
2. Can i somehow compile the struct (i doubt) in c without having to implement a c function that does the cast?

NB:
I'm using boost in the library, if needed

Regards

Comment: All `#pragma`, by _definition_, are optional additional features that compilers may implement or not. And in present case, I was even unaware that a `#pragma` exists to change locally endianness. But definitely not a solution if you need portability.

Comment: Any such `reinterpret_cast` leads to undefined behavior anyway.  Since the compiler would obviously have to swap bytes to use your structure, why not just swap the bytes yourself (into another object)?  Optimizers generally know better than to actually store the bytes back to memory if you do that one element at a time.

Comment: Not really interested in portability, mingw and gcc/g++ are the current actors here